# Having a hard time with Entity Framework detached POCO objects

Tags: entity-framework

I want to use EF DbContext/POCO entities in a detached manner, i.e. retrieve a hierarchy of entities from my business tier, make some changes, then send the entire hierarchy back to the business tier to persist back to the database. Each BLL call uses a different instance of the DbContext. To test this I wrote some code to simulate such an environment.

First I retrieve a `Customer` plus related `Orders` and `OrderLines`:-

```
Customer customer;
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    customer = context.Customers.Include("Orders.OrderLines").SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == 1);
}
```

Next I add a new `Order` with two `OrderLines`:-

```
var newOrder = new Order { OrderDate = DateTime.Now, OrderDescription = "Test" };
newOrder.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine { ProductName = "foo", Order = newOrder, OrderId = newOrder.Id });
newOrder.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine { ProductName = "bar", Order = newOrder, OrderId = newOrder.Id });
customer.Orders.Add(newOrder);
newOrder.Customer = customer;
newOrder.CustomerId = customer.Id;
```

Finally I persist the changes (using a new context):-

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    context.Customers.Attach(customer);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I realise this last part is incomplete, as no doubt I'll need to change the state of the new entities before calling SaveChanges(). Do I Add or Attach the customer? Which entities states will I have to change?

Before I can get to this stage, running the above code throws an Exception:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.

It seems to stem from not explicitly setting the ID of the two `OrderLine` entities, so both default to 0. I thought it was fine to do this as EF would handle things automatically. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, working in this "detached" manner, there seems to be an lot of work required to set up the relationships - I have to add the new order entity to the `customer.Orders` collection, set the new order's `Customer` property, and its `CustomerId` property. Is this the correct approach or is there a simpler way?

Would I be better off looking at self-tracking entities? I'd read somewhere that they are being deprecated, or at least being discouraged in favour of POCOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have 2 options:

A) Optimistic.

You can proceed pretty close to the way you're proceeding now, and just attach everything as Modified and hope. The code you're looking for instead of .Attach() is:

```
context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Definitely not intuitive. This weird looking call attaches the detached (or newly constructed by you) object, as Modified. Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

If you're unsure whether an object has been added or modified you can use the last segment's example:

```
context.Entry(customer).State = customer.Id == 0 ?
                               EntityState.Added :
                               EntityState.Modified;
```

You need to take these actions on all of the objects being added/modified, so if this object is complex and has other objects that need to be updated in the DB via FK relationships, you need to set their EntityState as well.

Depending on your scenario you can make these kinds of don't-care writes cheaper by using a different Context variation:

```
public class MyDb : DbContext
{
    . . .
    public static MyDb CheapWrites()
    {
        var db = new MyDb();
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        return db;
    }
}

using(var db = MyDb.CheapWrites())
{
    db.Entry(customer).State = customer.Id == 0 ?
        EntityState.Added :
        EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You're basically just disabling some extra calls EF makes on your behalf that you're ignoring the results of anyway.

B) Pessimistic. You can actually query the DB to verify the data hasn't changed/been added since you last picked it up, then update it if it's safe.

```
var existing = db.Customers.Find(customer.Id);
// Some logic here to decide whether updating is a good idea, like
// verifying selected values haven't changed, then

db.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(customer);
```

Comment: That's something for me to look into but I still don't understand the exception I'm getting. I didn't think I had to assign primary key IDs to new entities - I thought EF took care of that for me. Or is that only in an attached scenario?

Comment: Well, if you take a look at the documentation I linked there, the .Attach() method is meant for existing, NotModified entities. If your OrderLines are new objects, then they meet neither of those criteria. NotModified objects have their Key (usually .Id) honored on their way into the database; a 0 is causing the Exception. So the solution is to attach them as above, which causes it to instead Insert them without including the Key, and of course then the db sets the Key (again, .Id) for you because it's an Identity column. Basically .Attach() is kind of confusing and should probably be avoided.